# JavaScript to detect when a word is "found" by the browser search feature

Tags: javascript, search, browser

In my web page, certain sections are collapsed. Suppose the visitor searches for a word which appears in one of these collapsed sections. Is there a way that JavaScript can detect which words have been found, so that I can expand the appropriate sections and show the words?

I have discovered that browsers tend to ignore words in text that is treated either as `{display: none;}` or `{height: 0;}`, but that words in a section with `{height: 1px;}` are found by the search feature.

You can find a demo of this in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kc6bfow2/2/).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680213/is-there-a-way-to-detect-find-on-the-page-searches-in-javascript

Comment: Not in any general way; searching is (always, AFAIK) handled "out-of-band", e.g., it's internal to the browser, not part of the page.

Comment: `selectionchange` event works on Firefox and IE, but not Chrome. (a _bit_ late to this question though)