# Detect page find/search to expand a collapsible

Tags: javascript, dom-events

My team is using an expandable box to condense info on our wiki (in Confluence), it's pretty standard using `display:none/block`. I'd like this to work with the browser's find functionality. I've found that when I switch to hiding the content using `max-height` the browser at least finds the text correctly, but I'd like to expand the collapsible when a match is found inside it and re-collapse it when find is no longer looking at it. Is there a way to do that?

I've already tried the `focus` and `selectionchange` events to no avail. I guess I could track scrolling for jumps or track keystrokes but neither of those really tells me if the collapsible is where the query was found.

tl;dr is there a way to detect browser find?

**Update:** Here's an idea of what the code looks like:

```
var expand = document.querySelector('.expand');
expand.querySelector('.head').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 //toggle a class .show on .expand
})
```

And my CSS:

```
.expand .body {
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    padding: 0 20px 0 40px;
    transition: all .4s;
}
.expand.show .body {
    max-height: 3000px;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px 40px;
}
```

Comment: Add some code please.  What you're trying to do might make more sense if we can see that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to detect find on the page searches in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680213/is-there-a-way-to-detect-find-on-the-page-searches-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can detect key press combination such as Ctrl+F like below

```js
var map = {17: false, 70: false};
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode in map) {
        map[e.keyCode] = true;
        if (map[17] && map[70]){
            // FIRE EVENT YOU EVENT
        }
    }
}).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode in map) {
        map[e.keyCode] = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, but that won't tell me if something was found inside my collapsible

Comment: It also won't help if the user selects Find from the Edit menu rather than pressing Ctrl+F.

Comment: Yes, Definitely it won't help in that case, remember we can't control those things while dealing with a web app.

Comment: @Airhogs777 Your custom logic to find something or to tell something you can implement where i wrote // FIRE EVENT YOU EVENT.