# How to check wheather browser search (using Ctrl+F) option is opened via java Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, browser

I need to find out if user has opened the browser's search using Ctrl+F. Is there any events or variables to check it?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680213/is-there-a-way-to-detect-find-on-the-page-searches-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Simply check for the key combination `Ctrl+F`:

```
function keyPress(e) {
      var evtobj = window.event ? event : e
      if (evtobj.keyCode == 70 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {
          //do something
      }
}

document.onkeydown = keyPress;
```

For clarification, the key `F` has the keyCode `70`.

Comment: Of course, this doesn't detect someone going Menu > Search

Comment: Some browsers use `which` instead of `keyCode`. So, it is better to use `var key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;` and also the `keypress` event is usually better.